# Find path to subnodes of treeview using linq. (Completely flattening a treeview)

Tags: c#, linq, treeview

I have a treeview:

```
A0 -----
A1 -----
A2 
   B0 ----
   B1 ----
       C0 ----
       C1 ----
```

The main branches, A0, A1, A2 are of the same type. B0, B1 are of the same type. 
C0, C1 are of the same type. Types A, B, and C are different types. I need to get the path from each top node down through all its subbranches to its terminal child node. That is (assuming each level can be represented as a string), output needs to be:

1. A0
2. A1
3. A2 -- B0
4. A2 -- B1 -- C0
5. A2 -- B1 -- C1

Where each listing is one path.

This problem hits me as being something similar to a left join on database tables. How can this be done? (linq ??).

Thanks for any help.

Edit #1: **Here is the complete definitions of each branch. Hope it helps.**

Showing more information, each of the "A" objects are created with:

```
view_consulting[] v = MyNetwork.Medical.Client.GetConsultingStaff();
            var s = v.GroupBy(p => p.speciality_name).Select(q => new SpecialityTreeItem(q));
```

That is "A" is SpecialityTreeItem.

```
 public class SpecialityTreeItem : SimpleViewModelBase
    {
        #region [Fields]
        private string _speciality;
        #endregion

        #region [Constructors]
        public SpecialityTreeItem() { }

        public SpecialityTreeItem(string speciality_name  )
        {
            Speciality = speciality_name;

            var _offices = MyNetwork.Medical.Client.GetOffices(speciality_name);

            Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeTreeItem>(
                  _offices.Select(q => new OfficeTreeItem(q.office_name, Speciality) { City = q.city, Phone = q.phone, Fax = q.fax }));
        }

        public SpecialityTreeItem(IGrouping<string, view_consulting> specialityGroup)
        {
            Speciality = specialityGroup.Key;

            // Create a subgroup for office under each SpecialityTreeItem for each office name.
            var _offices = specialityGroup.Where(q => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.office_name))
                .GroupBy(q => q.office_name)
                .Select(y => new OfficeTreeItem(y)).ToList();

            Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeTreeItem>(_offices);
        }

        // Constructor to build a tree with single branches per level. (i.e., only one office per speciality, or one doctor per office).
        public SpecialityTreeItem(SpecialityTreeItem sti, OfficeTreeItem oti, DoctorTreeItem dti)
        {
            Speciality = sti.Speciality;
            Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeTreeItem>();

            if (oti != null)
            {
                var m = new OfficeTreeItem[]{ new OfficeTreeItem(oti,dti)};
                Offices = new ObservableCollection<OfficeTreeItem>(m);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region [Properties]
        public string Speciality
        {
            get { return _speciality; }
            set { if (_speciality == value) return; _speciality = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<OfficeTreeItem> Offices { get; set; }
        #endregion

    }
```

The second level "B" is Offices:

```
public class OfficeTreeItem : SimpleViewModelBase
    {
        #region [Fields]
        private string _speciality;
        private string _officeName;
        private string _city;
        private string _phone;
        private string _fax;
        #endregion

        #region [Constructors]
        public OfficeTreeItem() { }

        public OfficeTreeItem(IGrouping<string, view_consulting> officeGroup)
        {
            OfficeName = officeGroup.Key;
            Speciality = officeGroup.First().speciality_name;

            var _doctors = officeGroup.Where(q => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q.lastname))
                .GroupBy(q => new { q.lastname, q.firstname, q.speciality_name })
                .Select(y => new DoctorTreeItem() {
                    FirstName = y.Key.firstname, LastName =y.Key.lastname, Speciality = y.Key.speciality_name
                });

            Doctors = new ObservableCollection<DoctorTreeItem>(_doctors);

        }

        public OfficeTreeItem(string Office_Name, string speciality_name)
        {
            OfficeName = Office_Name;
            Speciality = speciality_name;

            view_consultant[] _doctor_office = MyNetwork.Medical.Client.GetConsultants(OfficeName, Speciality);
            Doctors = new ObservableCollection<DoctorTreeItem>(
                _doctor_office.Select(q => new DoctorTreeItem() { LastName = q.lastname, FirstName = q.firstname, Speciality = q.specialty_name}
                ));
        }

        public OfficeTreeItem(OfficeTreeItem oti, DoctorTreeItem dti)
        {
            OfficeName = oti.OfficeName;
            City = oti.City;
            Phone = oti.Phone;
            Fax = oti.Fax;

            Doctors = new ObservableCollection<DoctorTreeItem>();

            if (dti != null)
            {
                var m = new DoctorTreeItem[]{dti}; 

                Doctors = new ObservableCollection<DoctorTreeItem>( m );
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region [Properties]
        public ObservableCollection<DoctorTreeItem> Doctors { get; set; }
        public string Speciality
        {
            get { return _speciality; }
            set { if (_speciality == value) return; _speciality = value; RaisePropertyChanged();  }
        }
        public string OfficeName
        {
            get { return _officeName; }
            set { if (_officeName == value) return; _officeName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string City
        {
            get { return _city; }
            set { if (_city == value) return; _city = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string Phone
        {
            get { return _phone; }
            set { if (_phone == value) return; _phone = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string Fax
        {
            get { return _fax; }
            set { if (_fax == value) return; _fax = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

The final level "C" is Doctors:

```
 public class DoctorTreeItem : SimpleViewModelBase
    {
        #region [Fields]
        private string _lastName;
        private string _firstName;
        private string _speciality;
        #endregion

        #region [Constructor]
        public DoctorTreeItem()
        {
        }

        public DoctorTreeItem(DoctorTreeItem dti)
        {
            LastName = dti.LastName;
            FirstName = dti.FirstName;
            Speciality = dti.Speciality;
        }


        #endregion

        #region [Properties]
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { if (_lastName == value) return; _lastName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { if (_firstName == value) return; _firstName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public string Speciality
        {
            get { return _speciality; }
            set { if (_speciality == value) return; _speciality = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        #endregion
    }   
}
```

Comment: Iterate the leaf nodes, return its parents and it. You'll need to have some code which shows what data you have. Only the parent, only the children?

Comment: @MineR Please see completed definitions, How can the leaf nodes be iterated? Thanks.

Comment: Because each of the items at each level is not currently the same, you can't do it in a generic way. In SimpleViewItemBase, make each of them have a "Name" and a "Children" (of type IEnumerable<SimpleViewItemBase>) and you can do it in a generic way.

Comment: Or do it with an interface, which you may prefer.

Comment: @MineR An interface seems much more preferable.Thanks.

Comment: @MineR I never can figure out why questions -- especially those with complete information -- are downvoted. Your suggestions have pointed me towards a workable reconfiguration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need a recursive function, not linq...

If you had a generic treeview control with Nodes and an arbitrary hierarchy, you could have a function similar to this:

```
public string GetPaths(int pathCounter, TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Nodes.Count == 0)
            sb.Append($"{pathCounter++} {node.FullPath}\n");
        else
            sb.Append(GetPaths(pathCounter, node.Nodes));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

But, you have three specific and distinct classes in a hierarchy.  So, for this specific example, I would write something like this:

```
public string GetPaths(IEnumerable<SpecialityTreeItem> stil)
{
    int pathCounter;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var sti in stil)
    {
        if (sti.Offices.Count == 0)
            sb.Append($"{pathCounter++} {sti.Speciality}\n");
        else
        {
            foreach (var oti in sti.Offices)
            {
                if (oti.Doctors.Count == 0)
                    sb.Append($"{pathCounter++} {sti.Speciality} -- {oti.OfficeName}\n");
                else
                {
                    foreach (var dti in oti.Doctors)
                    {
                        sb.Append($"{pathCounter++} {sti.Speciality} -- {oti.OfficeName} -- {dti.LastName}, {dti.FirstName}\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

which is somewhat ugly.  The issue is that each of the classes in the hierarchy has a different property to get to the next level in the hierarchy, so a recursive function cannot be used.  If you could use a common name instead of `Offices` and `Doctors`, that could help, but your `DoctorTreeItem` doesn't support having subordinate items.

At a minimum, I would override the `ToString()` method in all of the classes so that the somewhat ugly method outlined above would become a little cleaner as shown below:

```
public string GetPaths(IEnumerable<SpecialityTreeItem> stil)
{
    int pathCounter;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var sti in stil)
    {
        if (sti.Offices.Count == 0)
            sb.Append($"{pathCounter++} {sti}\n");
        else
        {
            foreach (var oti in sti.Offices)
            {
                if (oti.Doctors.Count == 0)
                    sb.Append($"{pathCounter++} {sti} -- {oti}\n");
                else
                {
                    foreach (var dti in oti.Doctors)
                    {
                        sb.Append($"{pathCounter++} {sti} -- {oti} -- {dti}\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Hope this answers your question.